# Problem with simple jQuery Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tabs

I have a very simple jquery tabs functions that looks like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Default Action
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
    $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

    //On Click Event
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
        return false;
    });

});
```

and the HTML for it is :

```
<div class="container">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab_container">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
      <h2>Content</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
      <h2>Content</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="tab3" class="tab_content">
      <h2>Content</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="tab4" class="tab_content">
      <h2>Content</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What im trying to do here is add another tab navigation, so bacically repat the ul tag with content in it but different class so I can have something like this :

```
<ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="markers">
        <li><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

..and whenever I click on any of the list it will affect

in other  group.

Any help much appreciaated.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Dom

Answer (score 1):

try to put a class for `<a>` tag a grab that tag using the class identifier
as

```
var activeTab = $(this).find("a.classname").attr("href");
```

it will only affect the tags whose class is matched with the one you specified

Answer (score 1):

you sholud use a class name or id or an element to use `fadein()` like this

```
 $("#id").fadeIn("slow");
```

but in your code you are trying to use `href` attribute .

here.................

```
var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
$(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
```

i think you can't use like that

http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/